# Htaccess - Rewrite URL with multiple different conditions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make URL friendly with multiple conditions.

I got this: `www.example.com/?lang=en&page=test&model=mymodel`

I want to have: `www.example.com/en/test/mymodel`

But I got also this (with other parameters):

`www.example.com/?lang=en&otherpage=othertest&othermodel=myothermodel`

Must be:

`www.example.com/en/othertest/myothermodel`

How can I do this for my entire website?

Comment: You should think the other way, that is: given a friendly url, Apache needs a rule to map it to a unique "non-friendly" url. In your 2 friendly urls examples, it wouldn't be possible to distinguish the 1st one from the 2nd one (they have exactly the same pattern: language/value1/value2, with no clue to map value1 to page instead of otherpage, and value2 to othermodel instead of model.

Comment: I was hopping there were a solution to do it. A sort of condition, if exist parameter "test" do that, else ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use friendly URLs that look like this:

```
www.example.com/<language>/<value1>/<value2>
```

then Apache *won't* be able to distinguish between the first and the second "non-friendly" URLs that you mentioned:

```
www.example.com/?lang=en&page=test&model=mymodel
www.example.com/?lang=en&otherpage=othertest&othermodel=myothermodel
```

This is because the parameter names (`page` and `model` in the 1st, `otherpage` and `othermodel` in the 2nd URL) are not present, and can't be guessed, from the friendly URL.

A possible workaround depends on how many different scenarios you have, that is, how many different parameters you want to handle.

E.g. if you only have a few scenarios, you can add a part to the friendly URL pattern telling Apache **which parameter names** to use, like so:

```
www.example.com/<language>/<parameter_set>/<value1>/<value2>
```

then, tell Apache to use the first parameter set if `<parameter_set>` equals e.g. 1, the second set if it equals 2 and so on.

A sample rewrite rule set could be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/1/([\w]+)/([\w]+)$ ./?lang=$1&page=$2&model=$3
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/2/([\w]+)/([\w]+)$ ./?lang=$1&otherpage=$2&othermodel=$3
```

Please note that `1` and `2` are completely arbitrary (they could be any other string).

Naturally, [the official docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) are there to help.